# How can I make an auto-increment primary key to be increased based of the insertions that have the same second primary key same instead of all entries

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want to make a table which would have the available jobs of some companies.
The table will have to different primary keys, id and company, with id being an auto-incremented value, as there isn't any reason for the user to put manually the id.
I don't want to simply have the id increased every time a row get insertion, but to have different numbers depending on the different companies, as each company cares only for their jobs and I don't know from before how many companies I am going to have.

For instance:

Table jobs:

| id | company |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Apple |
| 3 | Apple |
| 1 | Amazon |
| 2 | Amazon |
| 1 | Sony |
| 4 | Apple |

etc.

How to do the above without making creating manually a table for each individual company?

Comment: You shouldn't want this: an id should have no information other than being unique.

Comment: But wouldn't the compination of the keys company and id be unique?

Comment: Yes, it would, but you are trying to bring in some extra logic in the value of it. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want the id to be easier to remember? Again, in my opinion, you shouldn't give any meaning to an id field.